# JSON.parse, already in try/catch block, still throws syntax error

Tags: javascript, json, node.js, callback

```
parseJsonMsg(msg, jsonCallBack) {
  try {
    let content = JSON.parse(msg.content);
    jsonCallBack(null, content);
  } catch (err) {
    console.log('[MSG processing ERROR]: ', err.message);
    jsonCallBack(err);
  }
}
```

This code is used to log the error whenever it is unable to parse a message.
Apart from logging, this throws syntax error if unable to parse. Why is that so? How can it be handled?

Any advice would be great

Comment: What is the error message that is thrown? And at which of those lines is it thrown?

Comment: It seems like you forgot the function keyword.

Comment: function keyword isn't required in several cases

Comment: @0x539 it could be a method of a class.

Comment: Yeah, I know. But looking at his code i'm not sure if it's a property or not.

Comment: yes, it is an object property

Comment: @t.niese well, no, you can do `const x = { parseJsonMsg () {}}` too.

Comment: @Kevin B I believe this is a ecmascript 6 feature

Comment: @KevinB seems as I need keep me more up to date :D

Comment: Thanks, guys, i was able to resolve my error. Nothing wrong with this script but with the function expecting this callback. Also, this is the structure i am using for my class, class Worker {

    constructor () { }

    start () { }

    parseJsonMsg () { }
}

Answer (score 1):

I suspect it is the method you are passing in as a parameter that is throwing the error. Make sure jsonCallBack does its own error handling. What is the error you receive?

Errors can be thrown anywhere, including inside catch blocks. If an error is thrown in a catch block it will percolate up the stack until it is either caught or the stack is exhausted and it becomes an uncaught exception.

Comment: Your comment helped me to figure out the error. Thanks, I am new to javascript. The error was with the function expecting this callback.

Answer (score 0):

bit of rewrite

```
parseJsonMsg(msg, jsonCallBack) {
  var err;
  var content;
  try {
    content = JSON.parse(msg.content);
  } catch (ex) {
    console.log('[MSG processing ERROR]: ', err.message);
    err = ex;
  }
  jsonCallBack(err, content);
}
```

then as said above, the parse error is forwarded to the caller in `jsonCallBack(err)`

So it may be the caller which throws the error.

To fix your problem, you should not comment that call `jsonCallBack(err)` but, depending on the type of caller, bind its error handler then decide what to do.

Comment: Thanks for the detailed response. It helped.